# How to make a circled bubble plot using ggplot2 coord_polar()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bubble-chart

I have an example data, which does not have x- and y-axis information. I would like to make a bubble plot using R package ggplot2, and arrange the bubbles in a circled manner.

```
data <- data.frame(group = paste("Group", letters[1:11]), 
                   value = sample(seq(1,100),11))
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put a dummy value for `y` and make `group` your `x` values in `aes`.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = 0, size = value)) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_point()
```

[image: polar bubble plot]